# scala static code analysy by using sbt-scapegoat - gettting dependency error

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying code coverage analysis using sbt-scapegoat package but I am getting the below error

> Extracting structure failed, reason: not ok build status: Error
> (BuildMessages(Vector(),Vector(BuildFailure(sbt task failed, see log
> for details)),Vector(),Vector(),Error)) sbt task failed, see log for
> details

maybe it because of some dependency issue

**sbt version**

> 1.5.8

**build.sbt**

```
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.12.7"

coverageEnabled := true

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalatest/scalatest
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.10" % Test
```

**plugins.sbt**

```
addSbtPlugin("org.scoverage" % "sbt-scoverage" % "1.5.1")

addSbtPlugin("com.sonar-scala" % "sbt-sonar" % "2.3.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.sksamuel.scapegoat" % "sbt-scapegoat" % "1.1.1")
```

**NOTE:-** I have referred to this [link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sksamuel.scapegoat/scalac-scapegoat-plugin) and tried for all possible versions from 1.1.0 to 1.4.11

plz help to understand the error
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your **sbt** version? - Also, have you tried upgrading to **Scala** `2.12.15` and using the latest version of **Scapegoat**?

Comment: hi @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, my sbt version is 1.5.3, i have updated that in question and I didn't try with V2.12.15
I will try and let you know

Comment: Try also using **sbt** `1.5.8`

Comment: with version 2.12.15 i am getting this error

Comment: Extracting structure failed, reason: not ok build status: Error (BuildMessages(Vector(),Vector(),Vector(),Vector(),Error))

Comment: and sorry, sbt version is 1.5.8 only. by mistake I mentioned wrong version

Comment: Uhm, feels like a bug in **Scapegoat** you may open an issue but the project is mostly dead AFAIK.